# Bot Framework Emulator - Taking longer than usual to connect

Tags: azure, frameworks, botframework, bots

I have this issue since yesterday. In the `Welcome`-Tab I click on `Open Bot`. Then I type `http://localhost:3978/api/messages` into `Bot URL or .bot file location`. Then I click on `Connect`.

My problem is that I cannot send any messages. Also there is the warning `Taking longer than usual to connect.`

This is the screen I'm looking at:

[image]

The thing is that it worked 2 days ago. Yesterday I got the issue and I just hoped that it would work the next day (so today). But the issue still remains.

How can I chat with my bot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run and deploy every new bot you have. Open the solution of the bot in Visual Studio and run it with F5. Then the bot is ready to be tested in the Bot Framework Emulator.

Comment: Correct, you will only see the "Taking longer to connect." warning message if the bot is not running locally. Make sure you start your bot before you try to connect to it. Best of luck!

Comment: actually npm start did it for me in visual code studio.  Not sure, but F5 just gave me so many issues, like having to add launch.json and I had to trace where this is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and @axbeit's answer helped. For some reason, my bot **switched from port 3978 to port 5000**, so I updated my .bot file accordingly.