# Bot Framework Emulator - Cannot connect to local bot

Tags: botframework

I am trying to connect to a local bot which has been pulled from a shared repo. Other developers have had this running and connected successfully. Points I have checked:

- App is running.
- Correct URL
- Correct AppId/AppPassword
- I have also tried both with/without ngrox.

Error/warning recieved:  `Taking longer than usual to connect`

Any ideas what might be causing this to only fail on my machine?

Comment: Are you running a firewall? (first or third party)

Comment: No firewalls, I have disabled all but still no help

Comment: As per my experience if you want to run it locally comment `AppId/AppPassword` from`appsettings.json` then you can connect it from emulator. otherwise it creates issue sometimes reason unknown.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron unfortunately did not help

Comment: Do you want to connect your `azure published` bot through emulator?

Comment: No this is a locally running bot

Comment: just a few things to double check:make sure the bot is running locally(F5 on VS) and then connect to the Emulator. If you are testing locally, you can just connect using the URL and comment out the appId/password in the bot code. Also, make sure your bot is running on the correct port before trying to connect it. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56972476/bot-framework-emulator-taking-longer-than-usual-to-connect and https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/issues/1755

Comment: what version of the Emulator are you on?

Comment: Emulator V4.7.0

Comment: @ranusharao I have checked all of these and nothing seems to help

Comment: @andyb952 are you behind a proxy or on a corporate network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out. Running under IIS Express caused this issue for me. Changing to use the CLI and command `dotnet run` instead solved the issue.

Very bizzarre, I should think a re-install of IIS-Express will then sort it out. Thanks for the comments though.